# In database query theory, why do we not want to use a constant that isn't in the dictionary?

Tags: database-theory

A badly explained textbook example asks the following:

Suppose we have a definition of the dictionary our database will use (that is, it's relations and constants), defined as:

$<R_\le (?, ?), R_+(?,?,?), R_*(?, ?, ?), c_0, c_1>$

where $R_{operation}$ defines the nature of the relationship of the values inside (represented as question marks), and $c_{value}$ represents a constant. For example, $R_+(a, b, c)$ means that $a + b = c$.

If we build a database structure using our dictionary over the real numbers with constants defined as $1, 0$ we have

$<\mathbb{R}, r_\le, r_+, r_*, 1, 0> $

The questions asks:
Write a query that will return all the points on the graph between the lines

- $y = x$
- $x = 2$
- $y = 0$

[image: x=y, y=0, x=2]

**ANSWER**
The answer given is:

$R_\le(y,x) \wedge R_\le(c_0,y) \wedge ∃a(R_+(c_1,c_1,a) \wedge R_\le(x,a))$

What's not explained however, is why the last constraint is so long? Instead of writing $∃a(R_+(c_1,c_1,a) \wedge R_\le(x,a))$, why don't we just say $R_\le (x, 2)$?

What benefits are we getting by doing it this roudabout way?

I understand it has something to do with only using our constants, but 2 is in our domain, why can't we use it?

Please explain, thank you so much.